# Why is Hindu food not allowed? How are they najis?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophets, food, hindu

Why are we not allowed to eat [Hindu food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diet_in_Hinduism)?

The answer given is coz they are najis! How are they najis? And during the Prophet's time, there were many non-Muslims, yet they had a good relation with the Prophet.  According to the reasons given to me, it does not really make sense that the Prophet would actually say no to food brought in by the non-Muslims. Aren't we just hurting a person's feelings and getting sins and insulting food?  I always fail to understand this.

Comment: Salam and welcome to ISlam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour] and vsiit our [help] to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model. To your Question: Who gave this answer?

Answer (score 4):

The primary prohibition is limited to *meat* that is slaughtered by them because it will not be slaughtered in Allah's name, and it may be dedicated to their gods rather than to Allah.

> [Quran 6:118](https://quran.com/6/118) So **eat** of that [meat] **upon which the name of Allah
>   has been mentioned**, if you are believers in His verses.
>
> [Quran 6:121](https://quran.com/6/121) And **do not eat** of that upon which the **name of
>   Allah has not been mentioned**, for indeed, it is grave disobedience.
>   And indeed do the devils inspire their allies [among men] to dispute
>   with you. And if you were to obey them, indeed, you would be
>   associators [of others with Him].
>
> [Quran 6:145](https://quran.com/6/145) Say, "I do not find within that which was revealed to
>   me [anything] **forbidden** to one who would eat it unless it be a dead
>   animal or blood spilled out or the flesh of swine - for indeed, it is
>   impure - or it be [that slaughtered in] disobedience, **dedicated to
>   other than Allah** . But whoever is forced [by necessity], neither
>   desiring [it] nor transgressing [its limit], then indeed, your Lord is
>   Forgiving and Merciful."
>
> [Quran 2:173](https://quran.com/2/173) He has only **forbidden** to you dead animals, blood, the
>   flesh of swine, **and that which has been dedicated to other than Allah**
>   . But whoever is forced [by necessity], neither desiring [it] nor
>   transgressing [its limit], there is no sin upon him. Indeed, Allah is
>   Forgiving and Merciful.

Apart from this several other prohibitions also come into effect. Halal food can not include pork, carrion, blood, wine or an animals slaughtered by other than the exsanguination (see [5:3](https://quran.com/5/3) and [5:90](https://quran.com/5/90)). Hindu food will normally not meet this requirement, and even when it is not meat itself, it may have ingredients of animal origin which may not be halal.

As such, meat is only permitted in Islam when it has been slaughtered by a Muslim, a Jew or a Christian:

> [Quran 5:5](https://quran.com/5/5) This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and
>   the **food of those who were given the Scripture is lawful** for you and
>   your food is lawful for them.

---

Their purely vegetarian food is permitted, however a secondary prohibiton may arise when it is contaminated by food that is not permitted to Muslims. This also makes eating in their utencils forbidden when the same utencils are used to serve haram food ... however the material najasat (impurity) is inherent to the food and not to the people themselves.

From [Tafsir Al Qurtubi on 5:5](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=5&tSoraNo=5&tAyahNo=5&tDisplay=yes&Page=2&Size=1&LanguageId=1)

> ولا بأس بأكل طعام من لا كتاب له كالمشركين وعَبَدة الأوثان ما لم يكن من
>   ذبائحهم ولم يحتج إلى ذكاة؛ إلا الجُبن؛ لما فيه من إنْفَحة الميتة
>
> For such people there is nothing wrong with eating their food when
>   they are not People of the Book, such as polytheists and idolaters,
>   when it is not of their slaughtered meat ... except cheese because it
>   may use [rennet] from a dead [or haram] animal.
>
> ولا بأس بالأكل والشُّرب والطَّبخ في آنية الكفار كلهم، ما لم تكن ذهباً
>   أو فِضّة أو جِلد خِنزير بعد أن تُغسل وتُغلى؛ لأنهم لا يتوقّون النجاسات
>   ويأكلون الميتات؛ فإذا طَبَخوا في تلك القُدور تنجّست، وربما سَرَت
>   النجاسات في أجزاء قُدور الفَخَّار؛ فإذا طُبخ فيها بعد ذلك تُوقّع
>   مخالطة تلك الأجزاء النّجسة للمطبوخ في القِدر ثانية؛ فاقتضى الوَرَع
>   الكفّ عنها
>
> It is permissible to use the utencils of the disbelievers to eat,
>   drink and cook ... when they are not made of gold, silver or the skin
>   of pigs etc. But the utencils should be washed before use, because
>   they do not refrain from impure foods and eat swine and carrion, and
>   when they use the utencils to cook they are made impure, and sometimes
>   the impuritites get stuck in the pores of pottery and may contaminate
>   whatever is cooked in it.

Comment: *Hindu food will normally not meet this requirement, and even when it is not meat itself, it may have ingredients of animal origin which may not be halal.* Acutally, ALL meat is frowned upon in Hinduism, so there are hardly any meat dishes that can be tagged "Hindu." Are any plants considered *haram*, though?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is perfect. Basically, it would not be allowed to eat Hindu slaughtered meat but nothing wrong with eating Indian food. Hindu is the religion and as they do not believe in Allah, they do not bless the meat in Allah's name upon slaughter. With Indians however, there are many Muslims. In fact, the largest Muslim population in numerical value is there so just make sure you realize that difference! You are allowed to eat vegetarian Hindu food however!

Answer (score -1):

Probably the peoples avoid that kind of food because of the following reasons.

1.The animals like dog ,pig are najis for Muslims .but the non Muslims will interact with them.if we don't sure about this we need to avoid foods from them.
2.Animals must be killed in the name of Allah,otherwise which not allowed for Muslims even if it's given by a Muslim.

there are so many reasons like this you need to be care about.